# React native Picker onValueChange is not triggering with multiline picker item

Tags: android, react-native, android-dialog, react-native-picker

I have added multiline support to the react native Picker by adding this

```
Android: Strings.xml    

  <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
       <item name="android:inputType">textMultiLine</item>
        ...
    </style>




 <Picker  style={styles.picker} 
    selectedValue={selectedValue} 
    onValueChange={(itemValue, index) => {
                      console.log(index)
      }
    } 
  >
    ... <picker items> ...

  </Picker>
```

Ref: [How to style the React-native picker items to wrap the lengthy text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55120972/how-to-style-the-react-native-picker-items-to-wrap-the-lengthy-text)

but unfortunately `onValueChange` is not triggering after adding multiline.

How can I get the onValueChange event on multiline Picker.

Am using RN .59.x (RN Upgrading is not feasible for me :( ) and picker mode as DIALOG

..

Any other option to add the multiline support other than updating the strings.xml

Sample (single line): https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker

[image]

Comment: Can you show a print how your picker is and its Dialog?

Comment: Added sample image  @GabrielMenezesdaSilva

we can run the sample application @ https://reactnative.dev/docs/picker